# How to get ride of positioning in mobile version of css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am making Responsive site. I have seen that absolute positioning has been used in some elements. How can i get rid of position in mobile version of coding declaring Media Queries.
Such as : For getting ride of float we use float:none in mobile version of Media Queries.
In this way how can i get ride of absolute and relative position using css.

Answer (score 1):

```
position: static;
```

This is the default, "normal" `position` for elements.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)